# Fetch in Expo SDK36 RN 0.61.4 returns as undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I was originally using this function to resize and then upload an image in an earlier version of Expo and it worked fine:

```
uploadImage = async (originalUri) => {
    const { dispatchAvatar } = this.props;
    const { uri } = await reduceImageAsync(originalUri);

    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const photoData = { uri, blob };

    dispatchAvatar(photoData);
};
```

In Expo SDK36 (RN 0.61.4) however, when I try to fetch the uri, the response returns as undefined. The uri is just a local file (file:///), and if I look at response.headers, I can see the "content-type": "image/jpeg", so the fetch is recognizing the file correctly.

When I try to log the response, I get:

```
console.error: "There was a problem sending log messages to your development environment",
Error: value.hasOwnProperty is not a function. (In value.hasOwnProperty('tag')', 
'value.hasOwnProperty' is undefined).
```

Any ideas what about upgrading to the newer version of Expo and React Native would have broken this? Doesn't work on an iOS device or the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed the updated example here and it worked fine:
https://github.com/expo/examples/blob/master/with-firebase-storage-upload/App.js